# angularjs doesn't show json data with http.get

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, http-get

i need to show json data in a table, and i used the http.get function to retreive json data but i don't be able to show them.

i've tried this but not working:

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js" />
        <script>
            myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
            myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){
                $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
                    $scope.myData = response;
                });
                $scope.removeName = function(row) {
                    $scope.myData.splice($scope.myData.indexOf(row),1)
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        Search: <input type="text" value="" ng-model="search" /><br><br>
        <table border=1>
            <tr ng-repeat = "Data in myData | filter : search">
                <td>{{myData.name}}</td>
                <td>{{myData.company}}</td>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="removeName(data)">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSON**:

```
[
 {"name":"Steve Jobs", "company":"Apple"},
 {"name":"Larry Page", "company":"Google"},
 {"name":"Bill Gates", "company":"Microsoft"},
 {"name":"Larry Ellison", "company":"Oracle"},
 {"name":"Sergey Brin", "company":"Google"},
 {"name":"Steve Wozniak", "company":"Apple"}

]
```

**CONSOLE ERROR**:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:6:412
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:40:222
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at cb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:43:336)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:20:390)
    at Bc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:21:179)
    at fe (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:20:1)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:317:386
    at HTMLDocument.b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js:189:487)
```

Can someone help me to solve this error?
Thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo, you are repeating myData into Data property, but you are outputing myData :)

```
<tr ng-repeat = "Data in myData | filter : search">
            <td>{{Data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{Data.company}}</td>
            <td><a href="" ng-click="removeName(Data)">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Try this, notice the change I made in {{ }}

Ok, this is working code - https://plnkr.co/edit/dLei9iIM9ddfBAjoAytZ I just replaced your angular with 1.5.6 and its working.

Comment: thank's but also with this modification the result didn't change, in output i have only one line with print "Data.name", "Data.company" and "Remove"

Comment: Can you please paste the data set your ajax call is returning? Also is there any error in your console?

Comment: yes i've an error in the console at file angular.js and it is this: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415)(…)

Comment: Well that error is a problem :) First of all, is there specific need to use angular 1.2 over like 1.5? And please paste the whole error into question

Comment: no, now i use angular 1.5.8 and the error is the same and i posted it in the question

Comment: Edited my answer, there is now link to working example on Plunker

Comment: thanks but now the console tell me another error and i don't see nothing under the search, thi is the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Paolo/Desktop/provaHTTPget/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Yeah, you need to run it from webserver, so download something like XAMPP or WAMP (on Windows) and place it in htdocs directory. This is not problem with your angular code, but with browser, it can't find the file.

Comment: And what are you opening in browser? You need to go to something like http://localhost

Comment: yes, i didn't pass through the localhost, now it works thank's a lot